# Iterated expectation Confusion

Tags: probability

I am trying to show that $E(XY)=E[X$$[E(Y|X)]$

Bu the law of iterated expectation $E(XY)=E[$$E[XY|X]]$

I am not sure as to how to proceed from here

Comment: As it is stated now, your version of the law of the iterated expectation makes little sense. You should just condition on $X$, not $X=x$.

Comment: @StefanHansen What is the difference?

Comment: Conditioning on $X$ gives you a random variable, conditioning on $X=x$ gives you a number, say $\varphi(x)$. However, the two quantities are related since $\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]=\varphi(X)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very informally (the formal/correct answer is given by Stefan) :

When we write $E[X Y|X=x]$ we are fixing the value of $X$, so this is equivalent to $E[x Y | X=x]= x E(Y |X=x)$ (The $x$ value comes out of the expectation because it's a constant).

When we write $E[X Y| X]$ the same applies: the value of $X$ is given, so with respect to that expectation it's a constant and it comes out that expectation $ E[X Y| X]=X E[Y| X]$

Comment: great, however I do not understand why the conditioning remains, i.e why doesn't $E[X Y|X=x]=xE[Y]$

Comment: Because the data in the conditioning remains: it not only informs you that the first factor is a constant, but it also says that the expectation of the second must take into account the given value of $X$

Comment: Yes that makes sense as $Y$ could depend on $X$, however in the case $E[U|U=2V]$, why is this not equal to $E[2V]$ but instead $E[2V|U=2V]$?

Comment: I'm not sure how your last question relates with the original, but: $E[U|U=2V]=E[2V|U=2V] \ne E[2V]$ because, again, the fact that $U=2V$ gives you aditional information. In general, a conditioning restricts your universe to a smaller one. Picture this example: suppose $(U,V)$ take values with uniform probabilities on the points $(2,1)$, $(0,0)$, $(2,-1)$ (each point has prob $1/3$). Here, the event $ U=2V$ restricts you to two points, each with prob $1/2$. Verify that $E(V)=0$ $E(U)=4/3$, $E(U | U=2V)=1=E( 2 V | U=2V) = 2 \times 1/2$

Answer (score 1):

By the law of the iterated expectation 
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[XY\mid X]]=\mathrm{E}[XY].
$$
However, since $X$ is measurable with respect to sigma-algebra that we condition on, we can "pull it out", i.e. we have $\mathrm{E}[XY\mid X]=X\mathrm{E}[Y\mid X]$.

Comment: Could you explain without referring to sigma algebras and measurability?, i'm just looking for the basic intuition.

Comment: Then _you_ need to tell us what your definition of conditional expectations are. Their definition usually involve sigma-algebras and measurability and hence requesting a solution that doesn't involve these terms seems rather odd.